# Python data error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '42152129.0'

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I am working on a simple data science project with Python. However, I am getting an error which is the following:

ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import csv
from datetime import datetime

filename = 'USAID.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
header_row = next(reader)

monies = []
for row in reader:
   money = int(row[1])
   monies.append(money)
print(monies)
```

if I change the line:

```
money = int(row[1]) to money = float(row[1])
```

I get this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float:
Here are my tracebacks: first error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "funding.py", line 60, in <module>
  money = int(row[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '42152129.0'
```

Second Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "funding.py", line 60, in <module>
  money = float(row[1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Any reason you don't just load this using pandas `read_csv` method? `df = pd.read_csv(filename)`? This will use the appropriate `dtypes` for your data, besides you can easily convert afterwards using `astype`: `df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: You didn't tell what you expect your code to do, and why is that. Errors are clear -  `'42152129.0'` cannot be unambiguously converted to int (because it's not valid string representation of int), `` (empty string) also cannot be unambiguously converted to float.

Comment: I was thinking about using Pandas and have been for the past few days, However, I wanted to plot the data and not sure how to do that in Pandas as of yet. I only want to plot data of financial aid to certain countries with the x-axis being dates and the y being the amount of money.

Comment: `pandas` supports plot methods and matplotlib, for instance you can just call `df.plot()` or `df.plot().barh()`, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#plotting)

Comment: oh I will check that out! It is what I really want to do but have not found a good tutorial that shows me using matplotlib and Pandas together. (Which is actually what I want, I will check the docs.)

Answer (score 5):

The first failure is because you passed a string with `.` in it to `int()`; you can't convert that to an integer because there is a decimal portion.

The second failure is due to a *different* `row[1]` string value; one that is empty.

You could test for that:

```
if row[1]:
   money = float(row[1])
```

Since you are working with a Data Science project you may want to consider using the [`pandas` project](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to load your CSV instead with [`DataFrame.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: or a `try-except` wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Some of the entries in `row[1]` are empty so you probably want to check for those before trying to *cast*. Pass a default value of, say `0`, if the entry is blank.

Then you should consider using [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) for computations that relate to money.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP's working with money. Marginal losses are not negotiable

Comment: Although pandas supports `decimal` it's a little problematic, I would stick to the numpy types like `float` and `float64` in this case

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while I was learning data visualization using Seaborn. Thanks [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum)'s help, I was able to solve the issue with his approach:

```py
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
```